# Is there any way to run Google Chrome without installation on a Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, installation, non-admin

I tried to install Google Chrome on my Mac school computer last night.

After I downloaded the .dmg, I opened it like I do with any other .dmg to get around actually putting the application into the application folder and dragged it to my desktop. When I opened it, it asked for an installation.

I clicked "Don't install" – the Google Chrome icon popped up on my dock, and it opened the browser. About a minute into actually using the browser, it closed and said that I did not have the authorization to do so.

Is there any way to get around this to actually use Google Chrome? Access of terminal is also denied on this computer.

TL;DR: I need a way to use Google Chrome on a Mac without an installation.

Comment: Have you tried talking to an administrator? Obviously you're not allowed to run stuff they don't want you to, and whether that's a stupid rule or not, you probably have to stick to it when you use their computers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this "portable" version of Chrome for OSX

http://www.freesmug.org/portableapps:chromium

Comment: Just an FYI, this is Chromium, not Google Chrome. It does not have all the same features, but is basically the same thing.

EDIT: Looks like it does not support retina displays! :(

Comment: Here is a list which contains the latest version, which does support retina display: http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxportableapps/files/Chromium/